# What is a quick way to establish that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\log n}{n^{3/2}}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What is a quick way to establish that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {\log n}{n^{3/2}}$ converges?

**Attempt:** I proved this using the Integral Test but the integral test is usually a bit tedious.

So, what could be a better way to establish convergence quickly?

Comment: $-\,\zeta'\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \approx 3.9322$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest would be to know that $\log n=O(n^{\varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, so $\frac{\log n}{n^{3/2}} = O(n^{-3/2+\varepsilon})$.

Since $-3/2+\varepsilon<-1$, the series converges (it is is eventually dominated by the series for $\zeta(3/2-\varepsilon))$.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cauchy Condensation Test:

$f(n)=\dfrac{\log n}{n^{\dfrac{3}{2}}}$
which is   a decreasing function

Consider $a>1$ then $f(a^n)=\dfrac{n\log a}{a^{\frac{3n}{2}}}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Since for $n$ large we have $$\log n \leqslant {n^{1/4}},$$
$$\frac{{\log n}}{{{n^{3/2}}}} \leqslant \frac{{{n^{1/4}}}}{{{n^{3/2}}}} = \frac{1}
{{{n^{5/4}}}}.$$
But $\sum{\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}}$ converges, we deduce $\sum{\frac{\log n}{n^{3/2}}}$ converges.

Comment: Can I ask you something? Why is $\log n\leq n^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Answer (score 1):

$n^{-s}=\exp(-s\log{n})$

$\implies -\frac{d}{ds}n^{-s}=n^{-s}\log{n}$.

And the derivative of $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ at $s=\frac{3}{2}$ is finite.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you got many proofs I'd like to generalize the result as follows $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\log n}{n^{p}}$$ converges iff $p>1$.